# How to remove ducplicate tags from custom tag list?

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkbox, tags

I have this code to display the tags which are used in the current category, includes child categories:

```
if (is_category( )) {
  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
}
query_posts('category_name='.$yourcat->slug.'');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  if( get_the_tag_list() ){
    echo $posttags = get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>');
  }
endwhile; endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Is it possible to remove duplicate tags? Right now the code shows some tags multiple times instead of once.

Another question about this code: How can I output each tag like this to create a checkbox form?

```
<input type="radio" name="tag" value="tag1" <?php if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "tag1") { echo "checked";}?>> Tag1<br>
```

Hopefully someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I forgot to mention that I use the code `if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "tag1") { echo "checked";}` at the end of the input field to check the checkbox when the tag is used, but if I use that code (which works in html) the page don't display properly.

Comment: Tags are duplicated, because you list posts tags which have the same tags. You need a just list of tags connected to post from current archive category?

Comment: I need a tag list (or radio checkbox list of it) from tags which are used within the current category, included the child categories. If you are on the child category page then it should only show tags which are used within this child category. With this code that works, but it should only show each tag once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit, but now you have an array of tag id's which you can use for any purpose, for ex. list added below.

```
if (is_category()){
  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
}
$tag_IDs = array();
query_posts('category_name='.$yourcat->slug);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $posttags = get_the_tags();
  if ($posttags):
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    if (!in_array($tag->term_id , $tag_IDs)):
       $tag_IDs[] = $tag->term_id; 
       $tag_names[$tag->term_id] = $tag->name;
     endif;
    }
  endif;
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();

echo "<ul>";
foreach($tag_IDs as $tag_ID){
    echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag_ID).'">'.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'</a>';
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: I've used id instead term_id, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! This codes works great! Now I tried to use this line of code to display input fields: `echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$tag_slug[$tag_ID].'"> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';` with this: `$tag_slug[$tag->term_id] = $tag->slug;` but that didn't work. Do you have any suggestions how I could do this?

Comment: Where you need this input?

Comment: Instead of `echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag_ID).'">'.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'</a>';` and it comes in the sidebar on each (child)category page.

Comment: if they are in right places (input in lower foreach, slug array just below $tag_names), they are workin fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, indeed it's working! Not sure why it didn't worked the first time. I forgot to mention that I use the code if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "tag1") { echo "checked";} at the end of the input field to check the checkbox when the tag is used, but if I use that code (which works in html) the page don't display properly.