# Cannot retrieve all tags from custom loop without duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, custom-tags

I have to retrieve all of the tags without duplicates from a custom tag list, so I followed the solution given at:

[How to remove ducplicate tags from custom tag list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945617/how-to-remove-ducplicate-tags-from-custom-tag-list)

I tried customizing the PHP code given in the solution as follows, only to get one tag ID returned by the foreach block:

```
if(is_category()):
 $category = get_query_var('cat');
  $categories = get_category($category);
 endif;
 $tagIDs = array();
 query_posts('category_name='.$categories->slug);
 if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
 $tags = get_the_tags();
 if($tags):
  foreach($tags as $tag){
   if(!in_array($tag->term_id, $tagIDs)):
    $tagIDs[] = $tag->term_id;
    $tagNames[$tag->term_id] = $tag->name;
   endif;
  }
  endif;
 endwhile; endif;
 wp_reset_postdata();
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach($tagIDs as $tagID):
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_tag_link($tagID).'">'.$tagNames[$tagID].'</a></li>';
 endforeach;
 echo '</ul>';
```

I have to retrieve all of the tag slugs without duplicates. How can I achieve that?

Comment: So, did the codes return anything? did `$tagIDs` contains all the tag ids?

Comment: $tagID only returns one ID, which is 9.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the way paginate_links() was set up fixed this issue.